# Are you allowed to tag questions by domain?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

Is tagging questions by domain allowed?  For example the [maps](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) tag has a good number of topics.

I would like to propose a [medicine](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) or [medical](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) for several of the questions here.  It seems like applications in medicine will have different design goals than something like [games](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games).  Before creating the tag, I wanted to check to see if this would be permitted.

Comment: Could you edit this to include links to the "several questions" you're looking at?

Comment: Are you talking general design in medical context, e.g. "logo for a pharma company", or some specific output, e.g. "medical illustration"? I'd say no to the former, yes to the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a slippery slope.

In all probability the [maps](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) and [games](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) tags should be removed if they don't drop off due to no usage by themselves.

It would be a mess to have a tag for every possible area where graphic design is used. You may was well just propose every noun have a tag.

Of course there are different design considerations based upon industry. But citing every industry in a tag is exceptional overkill. It would be akin to having a tag for every spot color one could use in printing -- needless minutia.

Comment: Maybe, but don't you think that there are different design considerations for a GIS/Mapping app than for a financial app than for a game.

Comment: That was my point @sixtyfootersdude the maps and games tags are just bad tags. We shouldn't create more bad tags just because a couple exist.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Scott's sentiments which I agree with, we only get 5 tag choices for a question.

I would often have to prioritise between tags when editing because too many were applicable already.

Adding another dimension of tag categories like this would essentially reserve a tag space on every question, leaving less space for more meaningful tags.

Comment: Good point about the 5 tag limit.